# Making MCRYPT working with PHP

Tags: installation, php, apache-http-server, libraries

I installed the mcrypt library, but for some reason Apache disregards it. The files are in place, reinstalling invokes messages that newest version is already installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it show up in phpinfo()?  What kind of error do you get when you try to call an mcrypt function?

Comment: It doesn't show up on phpinfo(). The only error message I can describe is the one I get from phpMyAdmin, that mcrypt it cannot load the mcrypt extension.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried restarting apache after installing?

Edit: Yes, that's how I would restart it.  Also FYI, after installing the mcrypt extension, you must then recompile php with the --with-mcrypt=/usr/local/bin/mcrypt option, except use the path to where the mcrypt extension is installed.

There are two individuals in the comments on this page who experienced the same error.  Might try their suggestions:  https://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.setup.php

Also, note the comment here regarding the same error: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.installation.php

Comment: I did, like so: "sudo apachectl restart". Any other way I should know about?

Comment: Also used "sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart"

Answer (score 1):

Which platform do you use? Are you using a Mac? Installing an Apache module on a Mac can be a tricky process.

Comment: Also, "how did you install the module?" - i.e. using a pre-built package, or by compiling it yourself?

Comment: Operating system also helps...